# Add DataAnnotations to properties outside entity class

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

i need to add dataannotation attributes to my entities, BUT, outside my entities. Why? All of my classes are generated by T4, and if i add some dataannotations to the properties (DisplayName, Min, Max, etc) they will be lost when i re-run the T4 to generate my entities. I want the entities to be generated by the T4 and then, in another class do something like:

Dog.Name.AddDataannotation(new DisplayNameDataAnnotation("My dog"));

The class would be something like

```
public class Dog
{
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

It'd be like a fluent api for dataannotations. In this way i would have my dataannotations separated from my entities and i could regenerate them without loosing them. If anyone asks i can´t use DTOs. Another thing, I have a class that validates an entity based on its DataAnnotations, I would like keep it working.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Thanks and sorry for my english!

Answer (score 1):

The `MetadataTypeAttribute` was designed to handle this scenario. It's not pretty, but should work.

The steps to take are as follows:

- Make sure your generated type is `partial`
- For each type where you want to add metadata, add a new partial class definition, specifying the `[MetadataType]` (e.g. `[MetadataType(typeof(DogMetadata))]`]
- Redefine the properties in your `DogMetadata`, adding attributes there

Full example:

```
//dog.generated.cs
partial class Dog
{
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//dog.cs
[MetadataType(typeof(DogMetadata))]
partial class Dog {}

class DogMetadata
{
    [DisplayName("My dog")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow, awful!!! I don´t mean your answer (great answer), the way to handle the scenario! But one question, supose that Name property of Dog class changes to Name1, in my ideal scenario    Dog.Name.AddDataannotation(new DisplayNameDataAnnotation("My dog")); would throw an exception because Name changed to Name1. In the sample you showed me this wouldn't happen and Dog class would have Name (from metadata) and Name1 from the generated code. Is my interpretation alright? If my interpretation is ok, then i need to say that i don´t want this to happen!!

Comment: You are right, that scenario will fail miserably. You could have a unit test that checks the metadatatype properties against the original properties, to make sure they exist.

Comment: Hey, that one is good! But if both are the DOG class, how do you make the comparisson??